# Getting JsonArray data from Jersey using Angular js

Tags: angularjs, rest, jersey

I am writing simple application with REST in the backend and Angular as frontend. And now I cant make them talk properly. 
My Jersey class gets some data from database make JSONArray from it and send it to response to get.

```
@GET
@Path("{userID}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getLearningList(@PathParam("userID") int userId)
{
    SqlConnector con = new SqlConnector();
    List<String> list = con.getUsersLearningList(userId);
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    jObj.put("list", list);
    JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
    return jArray.toString();
}
```

In Angular I am using angular-resourse to get data from REST and even I made isArray: true I am getting this error:

```
       Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

Here is my angular

```
myApp.factory('GetDataService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return {
        getData: function(url)
        {
            return $resource(url,{},{
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: true
                }
           })
       }
    }
}]);
```

SqlConnector is just my class which work with database.
I am completely new in Angular. Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you getting an exception in your jersey ?

Comment: @svarog No, in Angular

Comment: Can you inspect the response in for example Chrome DevTools and see what is actually returned?